# Aplicativo não reporta erro ao google play

Tags: android

Quando aparece aquela mensagem "Aplicativo parou" geralmente aparece um botão enviar relatório, onde esse erro vai ser enviado para o console de desenvolvedor do google play, porém com meu app não está acontecendo isso, alguém faz ideia de o porque?

Comment: Mateus, acredito que esteja instalando o seu app via USB não? Isso porque o dialogo para reportar erros só é exibido quando o aplicativo é assinado com um certificado de release e quando é instalado via Google Play (porque o relatório de erro vai para o console de desenvolvedor). Existem outras alternativas, mas você precisaria incluir algo no seu app para coletar os erros.

Comment: Estou instalando ele via google play também, porém quando dá erro ele nunca pede para reportar..